# Get detailed rating items of review in magento 2

Tags: magento2, review

How can I get Detailed Rating results programatically using product id in magento 2.3.5?

I want to display it on product page.

Like this:
Product: 5 stars
shipping: 4 stars

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get Product rating details by Product id with the use of `RatingFactory`. Check the below code for this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class ProductReviews extends AbstractModel{

    protected $_ratingFactory;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_ratingFactory;
    protected $_reviewFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
            \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory,
            \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewFactory,
        ) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
            $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
            $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        }

    public function getReviewCollection($productId){
        $collection = $this->_reviewFactory->create()
        ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
        )->setDateOrder();

    }

    public function getRatingCollection(){
        $ratingCollection = $this->_ratingFactory->create()
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->addEntityFilter(
            'product' 
        )->setPositionOrder()->setStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addRatingPerStoreName(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->load();

        return $ratingCollection->getData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think I expressed myself poorly. I want to get one value per time to use it to define some business rules, for sample:
0 to 20 per cent of shipping review = show text "bad product shipment" or something else. And to do this, I need to get this informations individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        ...
    }
    
    public function getRatingSummary()
    {
        ...
        $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
    
        return $ratingSummary;
    }
```